# Drawbacks of instantiate WinForm inside an ASP.NET MVC controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

As stated in the title I'm working on a legacy ASP.NET MVC project in which I found an atypical logic.
Sometimes in the backend, few private methods (called by some controller in some condition) instantiate an entire WinForm (from another project referenced as .dll) to reuse that logic (public method of that WinForm).

I am pretty concerned about that and the impact of this architecture, but I am not aware of any *real* drawback of that approach and I have a very limited refactoring budget to schedule.

So I would ask if is this an issue that needs to be addressed or if it is only a strange approach with no real drawbacks.

----EDIT : added exemplification code

```
public ActionResult ShowPurcheaseorderById (int poId)
{
    PurcheaseOrderBiz po = new PurcheaseOrderBiz();
    return PartialView(po.GetById(poId));
}
```

In the biz class

```
public PurcheaseOrder GetById ( int poId )
{
    //some code here
    if ( _userNeedToKnowSomething )
    {
        NotificationHelper.NotifyToUser(message);
    }
}
```

In the static helper class

```
public static void NotifyToUser ( string message )
{
    frmWarning wrn = new frmWarning();
    wrn.Message = message;

    wrn.Show();
}
```

I would like to emphatize that this is only an example (so fictional code) real case is pretty much more intricated; but i hope give you the idea.

When i run it with the debugger attached to IIS, a page return its content (has nothing to do with the frmWarning, for sake of simplicity image it as if it's the image of PO) and a little WinForm is showed on my desktop (that show the message)

Comment: I'm a bit lost here - how exactly does that even work? Surely that only works in development? If you mean that you're using a single method then no, you should pull that out into a reusable DLL.

Comment: i am also confused about that, but i have a second project (referenced by ASP.NET MVC ones) in which all winform dependency are contained.
When that strange "pattern" occured a real  winform appear on my debug machine (i suppose that when deployed using NETWORK_SERVICE as app_pool user the story may be different).
In my debug machine i am still starting from VisualStudio, in debug mode (with iis express)

Comment: This is not good practice, the require business logic should decoupled from WinForm. But if you have budget concern and cannot do it right now make sure :

- All the resources within winform instance are disposed properly.
- If any Frequent & common code that has serious performance concern from end user atleast pull it out from winform.

Comment: Can you share some code snippets with us? How does it instantiate WinForm? How does it "render" the form?

Comment: @Nenad In a static method (in the referenced project, not ASP.NET MVC one, but called by it in the controller) there is a "_ref = new CustomDialogForm()" and then a "_ref.Show()".At the moment, these instructions (in debug with IIS Express) show a form on my desktop machine (is dev/test dedicated machine). 
PS : sorry if i don't disclose any piece of code but there is nothign atypical or strange in the code itself and also i prefer to not disclose any piece of this corporate software.

Comment: @Skary no problem for proprietary code. Hypothetical samples are enough. I cannot recall `.Show()` method being standard WebForms method. What is the return type of your controller's action? Should be some kind of `ActionResult`.

Comment: @Nenad ah sorry i have missunderstood your question. Controller has "nothing" to do with the from (i mean he should has nothing to do..), he does it job but sometimes business classes involved ask user to aknowledge something, So yes controller return an ActionResult with the right page exactly as intended. Meanwhile the server render a form on the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example MVC application, that fetches some property of a Winforms application that is only present when a certain button is clicked on the form.

When running the MVC application on my local machine, the Winform is rendered each time the MVC Action is requested:

[image]

When running the same application on an IIS server, it seems that the window is not rendered - but that could be because it is running under the IIS User account, as mentioned in the question.

A solution could be to make sure you dispose of the Form in the MVC controller, when it is no longer needed:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string dataFromTheWinform = null;
    using (MyWinformsApp.Form1 temp = new MyWinformsApp.Form1())
    {
        temp.Show();
        temp.button1.PerformClick();
        dataFromTheWinform = temp.GetMyString();
        temp.Close();
    }

    ViewBag.MyString = dataFromTheWinform;

    return View("Index");
}
```

The Form is still rendered, but it is closed before the response is sent to the client.